# Install package error.(cl.exe)

Tags: python, pip, package, installation

I tried to install python package SimPeg(by setup.py install)

Error:

> error: Setup script exited with error: Command "cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox
>   /W3 /GL /D NDEBUG /MD
>   -IC:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-package s\numpy\core\include
>   -IC:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\si te-packages\numpy\core\include
>   -IC:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pytho n36\include -IC:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include /Tcdisc retize\TreeUtils.c
>   /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\discretize\TreeUtils.obj"  failed
>   with exit status 127

C++ builder already installed. Need your help.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take time to look over our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/) and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/) to learn more about this site and how it works.

Comment: running build_ext
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from
distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
building 'discretize.TreeUtils' extension
compiling C sources
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\discretize

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and installing this http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to reinstall whole Visual Studio package in this case